# insert c# code inside javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

Greetings, 
how can I inject c# code (my Model property) inside javascript? I want to do something like this:

```
$(".star<%=Model.ROWGUID %>").mouseover(function() {
    var span = $(this).parent("span");
    var newRating = $(this).attr("value");
    setRating(span, newRating);
});
```

This works fine for single view. But when I Render PartialView in loops it causes the problem. Even alert("test") in mouseover event is not executed

**EDIT**
Ok, I figured out where the problem was. This was missing:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: That should work, as far as I can tell. What problem are you facing ?

Comment: Is this a asp.net application?

Comment: yes, this is an asp.net mvc application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work fine, but only in an ASPX file.

Comment: I recommend to do it on Render